# How to set app-id, name and version by CLI or build.json in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to set the app-id, name and version dynamically by CLI or a separated config file like build.json? I can not find satisfactory information in the documentation. I don't use the build.json. But it looks like that this is for app signing only.

And the build CLI seems to accept only the build type and device. But maybe there are more parameters. Maybe in `buildConfig` or `platformOpts` https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/

My alternative is to write a node script to replace the data in the `config.xml`. But I prefer a more official solution.

Cordova Version 9

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and will add. [See the official message of a the Cordova member](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/issues/463#issuecomment-534645097)

In my case I write my own script to handle this.